# How to pipe Promise.allSettled for lodash/fp pipe? (Or any functional like pipe lib, ex: p-pipe)

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, lodash

**Would want to:**
write an entire chain of function calls as pipe (the pipe function can be from Lodash or other libs)

**My working but incomplete attempt:**
This works, I'm half happy with this but not 100% what I want:

```
import {filter, map, pipe} from 'lodash/fp';
const anAwesomeFunction = async stuff => {
const data = await fetchData(stuff);
  return {
    title: 'example',
    data
  };
};

const pipingRocks = await pipe(
   filter({status: 'fulfilled'}),
   map(
     (promiseLikeObj: PromiseFulfilledResult) => promiseLikeObj.value
   )
)(await Promise.allSettled(map(anAwesomeFunction, result)));
```

**What I'd *like* to have:**
As far as I read pipe from lodash doesn't get async functions: [lodash fp docs](https://gist.github.com/jfmengels/6b973b69c491375117dc#_mapiteratee-collection)

```
import {filter, map, pipe} from 'lodash/fp';
const anAwesomeFunction = async stuff => {
const data = await fetchData(stuff);
  return {
    title: 'example',
    data
  };
};

const pipingRocks = await pipe(
   map(anAwesomeFunction),
   Promise.allSettled, // here lies my doubt on how to bind it
   filter({status: 'fulfilled'}),
   map(
     (promiseLikeObj: PromiseFulfilledResult) => promiseLikeObj.value
   )
)(result);
```

I have also tried with: `import pPipe from 'p-pipe';`

Comment: The `lodash/fp` library is pretty dated, there is _one_ mention of `.then` in the docs, and only four mentions of `Promise`. Maybe consider `const then = curry((f, p) => p.then(f))` and `pipe(map(...), Promise.allSettled.bind(Promise), then(filter(...)), then(map(...)), ...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, soon after posting this question I gave one last shot and got it working with `p-pipe` (not with the lodash one), binding the Promise.allsettled as a Promise, just like:

```
import {filter, map} from 'lodash/fp';
import pPipe from 'p-pipe';

const anAwesomeFunction = async stuff => {
const data = await fetchData(stuff);
  return {
    title: 'example',
    data
  };
};

const pipingRocks = await pPipe(
   map(anAwesomeFunction),
   Promise.allSettled.bind(Promise),
   filter({status: 'fulfilled'}),
   map(
     (promiseLikeObj: PromiseFulfilledResult) => promiseLikeObj.value
   )
)(result);
```

I'm open to better suggestions.